# Created a custom Profile in Salesforce by Cloning the standard user profile

Tags: salesforce

I created a custom profile by cloning the standard user Profile ,but unable to see the account records (OWD for Accounts was Private), but created the sharing rules and enforced properly.

Answer (score 0):

If OWD is Private and the Profile does not have View All for Accounts, then sharing is going to be controlled by Sharing Rules and the Role Hierarchy.
Check the role of the user who owns the Account, check the role of the user who wants to view the Account.
As an Admin, you can click on the Sharing button on the Account record to see who has access and why.